# How to shorten the IF condition in a dynamic list?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web

In future I have many **if condition**, any idea to shorten the if condition for (Render Badge items)?

Today I just only have 4 item if in the future I have 20 or maybe 100 item, is it i need to code the if for 20 or 100 times?

I have tried many method, but I don't know how to make it.

Render Dynamic List

```
const medals = productItem.goldmedal || productItem.newitem || productItem.freedelivery;
        if (medals) {
            const iconBadge = $("<ul>", { class: 'icons' });
            function createMedal(src, text) {
                const badge =
                    $("<li>", { class: 'icon' })
                        .append($('<a>', { class: 'tpsTooltip skeleton_hide', href: '###', 'data-tippy-content': text })
                            .append($('<img>', { src: src, alt: text })))
                        .append($('<div>', { class: 'pl-placeholder_skeleton pl-placeholder_liIcon' }));
                iconBadge.append(badge);
            }
            createFeatureIcon.append(iconBadge);

            //Render Badge items (Below is the if condition code)
            if (productItem.goldmedal) {
                createMedal(plSettings.goldMetalSrc, plSettings.goldMetalText)
            }
            if (productItem.newitem) {
                createMedal(plSettings.newItemSrc, plSettings.newItemText)
            }
            if (productItem.newshop) {
                createMedal(plSettings.newShopSrc, plSettings.newShopText)
            }
            if (productItem.freedelivery) {
                createMedal(plSettings.freeDeliverySrc, plSettings.freeDeliveryText)
            }
        }
```

Settings

```
//Settings
var plSettings = $.extend({
    mainClass: 'item-wrapper',
    itemWrapperClass: 'item ripple-effect ripple-joya itemShadowLight',

    goldMetalSrc: '/img/tps/gold.png',
    goldMetalText: 'Gold Medal sellers stand out from millions of sellers, bringing more trust and peace of mind to your shopping experience',

    newItemSrc: '/img/tps/new.png',
    newItemText: 'New item',

    sellermedalSrc: '/img/tps/seller.png',
    sellermedalText: 'Top Seller',
       
    newShopSrc: '/img/tps/newshop.png',
    newShopText: 'New Shop In Joyacart',

    freeDeliverySrc: '/img/tps/freedelivery.png',
    freeDeliveryText: 'Free Delivery'
});
```

example data is below:

```
var data = {
    productList: [
        {
            id: "62276197-6059-4c21-9b40-c5b1d277e85d",
            link: "javascript:void(0)",
            imgurl: "/img/upload/png/joyacart_000001_12032019.png",
            text: 'Product 001',
            goldmedal: false,
            newitem: true,
            newshop: true,
            freedelivery: true
        },
        {
            id: "59de8216-052d-4e51-9f7d-7e96642ded62",
            link: "javascript:void(0)",
            imgurl: "/img/upload/png/joyacart_000002_12032019.png",
            text: 'Product 002',
            goldmedal: true,
            newitem: false,
            newshop: true,
            freedelivery: true
        }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a product item that looks like this(I assume you can't change that):

```
{
  id: "62276197-6059-4c21-9b40-c5b1d277e85d",
  link: "javascript:void(0)",
  imgurl: "/img/upload/png/joyacart_000001_12032019.png",
  text: 'Product 001',
  goldmedal: false,
  newitem: true,
  newshop: true,
  freedelivery: true
},
```

Let's create an array of keys from that object that tell you if you should show a medal for it:

```js
const medalItems = ['goldmedal', 'newitem', 'newshop', 'freedelivery'];
```

Now instead of multiple if statements you can iterate over these keys and call `createMedal` for all these that are true in `productItem`. Passing that medal key(eg. "goldmedal" or "freedelivery") to `createMedal` function

```js
for (const medal of medalItems) {
  if(productItem[medal]) {
    createMedal(medal);
  }
}
```

Now in createMedal you can get src and text based on that medal key, but you'll need to adjust settings accordingly (eg. src for `goldmedal` should be under `plSettings.goldmedalSrc`)

```js
function createMedal(medal) {
  const src = plSettings[medal + "Src"];
  const text = plSettings[medal + "Text"];
  ...
}
```

Not perfect because you'll need to keep plSettings in sync with productItems but it should work with your current data structures. And all you need to do to get new one to work is to add it to settings and medalItems array

Comment: Basically you create an array of keys in data element that describe medal situation.
Then you map over them and call createMedal for keys that are set to true(basically that's your if statements)
And in createMedal you get src and text based on that key from data
Eg. goldmedal src will be calculated like this: src = plSettings["goldmedal" + "Src"] which is equivalent to plSettings.goldmedalSrc

Comment: You'll need to change Settings tho, so that they match with keys in data elements